# Teamviewer on Windows Server machines?

Tags: windows-server, teamviewer

Can the free/personal mode of Teamviewer be installed and run on Windows Server operating systems?

I am planning on providing some remote service to an office in a different town.  They have one server and 3 workstations.  I think the server is either Windows Server or Windows SBS.

Comment: well, if the answer is still important, I can try installing a Server2008R2 into a VM and install TW on it. (Mention my name in comment if it is.)

Comment: @Shiki: yes, it would be good to know the answer. Thanks. I'm talking about the free version of TM.

Comment: Why not use remote desktop and forward ports?

Comment: With remote desktop the session is not visible to people at the remote location.

Answer (score 5):

Use Ninite. It is an automated install program that lets you select groups of programs and have them unattended install on your machine. Teamviewer 8 is one of the options, so go to the website  click on the teamviewer 8's checkbox, scroll down to the bottom and press get installer. You will then be brought to the download page and it will download a few hundred kb file. That is the automated install script which will download teamviewer 8 and automatically install it without doing the OS system check. I tested this on my OWN Windows Server 2008 R2 server and it works as of 1/13/2013.

Hope this helps.

ninite.com

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is to right click the setup file and go to compatibility and select Windows XP compatibility mode.

Once installed the program will run in regular mode.

Comment: Doesn't work - the installer is still able to detect the "server" OS.

Answer (score 3):

Setting up compatibility mode to Windows 98 / Windows Me, it worked for me. I installed Team Viewer for personal use in Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Install TeamViewer 7.0.12979.exe then update to TV8.
Don't forget to run as WinXP compatibility when install.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the free version of TV8 works fine on server 2003, despite the non-commercial option being greyed out. I did choose personal use on the TV website (which is true, I have a small home network and got Server 2003 through MSAA) when selecting the download though, not sure if that had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install the free version on any Windows Server version.
The installer will start, but when you have to select the usage, everything except "Company / Commercial Use" is greyed out.

[image]

I still haven't found a proper way around this apart from unpacking the files in the temp directory and running it that way, but half of the functions don't work, basically rendering it useless.

Looks like I'm stuck with RDP or the exploit-happy VNC variants :(

Comment: So you can afford Windows Server but not TeamViewer? Life sucks. What's wrong with RDP, though? It's gotten better and better in recent years. There are ways to get around the installation issue, but I have it from one of the people who worked for the company that produces TeamViewer, so I'm not going to disclose it. I agree with him, it's only fair to pay for commercial use.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED What makes you think he had to "afford" a Windows Server licence? There are ways to get it for free for personal or educational purposes. Teamviewer's assumption that Windows Server is purely for "Company / Commercial Use" is plain wrong.

Comment: Well, these licenses aren't exactly the cheapest. MSAA is an argument, of course. Still with the server versions you get two RDP connections plus one console connection included. What's wrong with that? Session shadowing offers similar functionality to TeamViewer/VNC, so why violate the license terms of another software in order to get something that is on board? RAdmin is another affordable solution, still cheaper than TeamViewer. I really don't get the reasoning, unless you are questioning the idea of making money with software.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I'm not arguing with the idea of making money with software, nor with using RDP as an alternative. I'm arguing with Teamviewer's assumption that everyone who is using Windows Server is doing so for commercial purposes, as well as your assumption that everyone who is using Windows Server paid for the full retail licence and thus can afford <software X>. Both assumptions are demonstrably wrong.

Comment: @Indrek: fair point. Got it.

Answer (score -2):

As [TeamViewer Support Center](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/kb/38-Which-operating-systems-are-supported.aspx) states:

```
TeamViewer is available for the following operating systems:

Windows
 - Windows 98/NT(Service Pack 6a, at least IE 5.5)/Millennium Edition
 - Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7
 - Windows Server 2003/Home Server/Server 2008/Server 2008R2/Home Server 2011
```

So it can be installed and run on Windows Server.

Comment: AFAIK, the free version doesn't work on Windows Server, as it's free for non-commercial use, and they assume Windows Server isn't. Not really sure though.

Comment: You can, but it takes a little fantasy. Using normal approach, the choice of "free for non-commercial use" won't be available to you.